# Finding an orthogonal basis of a union of two subspaces quickly

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonal-matrices

Let's say we have two row-orthonormal complex matrices $P \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times k}$ and $Q \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times k}$, $n + m < k$. Since those martices are row-orthonormal, rows of $P$ form an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{C}^n$, and rows of $Q$ form an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{C}^m$.

I want to find an orthonormal basis of the union space of $P$ and $Q$, i.e. a space spanned by the rows of matrix $ W = \left[ {\begin{array}{c} P \\ Q \end{array}} \right]$. I know that I can do the orthogonalization of $W$ using the Gram-Shmidt process. But is there a way to do it in a faster way, using the fact that both $P$ and $Q$ are already row-orthonormal?

Comment: I doubt it ... think about the case where $n=m=1$. Is there any way to convert the individual bases of $P$ and $Q$ to an orthonormal basis for $P+Q$ that isn't just Gram–Schmidt in disguise?

Comment: @GregMartin I get your point. The case where $n = m = 1$ is a base case, however, it is solved directly via projecting one basis vector onto another and normalizing, so $O(k)$ operations. The whole Gram-Shmidt takes $O(n^2 k)$ operations, but what if we can reformulate it in divide-and-conquer way, like a mergesort algorithm? If there is an "merge" operation for two orthonormal bases which is faster than $O(n^2 k)$, then we could apply it to $P$ and $Q$ directly.

Comment: "Projecting one basis vector onto another and normalizing" is exactly what Gram–Schmidt does. But hey, maybe there is some other method out there that I don't see....